# Is there a way to view the last modified date of the the Object Text in DOORS?

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm new to using DOORS and am trying to create a column/attribute that has the date of the last modification to the Object Text. I found the below code which uses "Last Modified On", but that that includes all attributes and I'm only concerned about the Object Text. Maybe there's a way to specifiy an attribute for this?

```
    Date dMod
    dMod = obj."Last Modified On"
    dMod = dateAndTime(dMod)
    display dMod ""
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such attribute on an attribute.
The only way to determine this is via the object's history. Below is the example script from DXL manual. The idea is to loop through the object's history until the history record's `type`is `modifyObject`and it's `attrName` equals 'Object Text'. Keep in mind, though, that the history in a module only goes back to the last baseline. So, you may have to browse through all baselines to find the history record you need. See Tony's "Smart History Viewer" at http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?page_id=125 for details.

```
// history DXL Example
/*
 Example history DXL program.
 Generate a report of the current Module's
 history.
*/
// print a brief report of the history record

void print(History h) {
    HistoryType ht = h.type
    print h.author "\t" h.date "\t" ht "\t"
    if (ht == createType ||
        ht == modifyType ||
        ht == deleteType) { // attribute type
       print h.typeName
   } else if (ht == createAttr ||
              ht == modifyAttr ||
              ht == deleteAttr) {
        // attribute definition
        print h.attrName
   } else if (ht == createObject ||
              ht == clipCopyObject ||
              ht == modifyObject) { // object
       print h.absNo
       if (ht==modifyObject) {
           // means an attribute has changed
           string oldV = h.oldValue
           string newV = h.newValue
           print " (" h.attrName ":" oldV " -> "  newV ")"
       }
   }
   print "\n"
}
// Main program
History h
print "All history\n\n"
for h in current Module do print h
print "\nHistory for current Object\n\n"
for h in current Object do print h
print "\nNon object history\n\n"
for h in top current Module do print h
```